# How can I use Turkish characters like 'ş ç ı ö' in an Android TextView?

Tags: android, character-encoding, special-characters, textview

I want to write 'ile' in android TextView but it isn't drawn correctly. How can use characters like this?

For example I set the my textview as 'çile' it shows as '?ile' instead; how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the font being used includes these characters?

Comment: it is not support some porteguse ,spanish ,italian characters too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer solved my problems for turkish characters.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312031/218198

Comment: This simple solution did not worked for SDK's 2.3 and 3.2 for me. To cover 2.3, 3.2 and 4.0 I added some more lines:
`String htmlData = "Html data with tags and turkish characters";`
`String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";`
`webView.loadData(header+htmlData, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", null);`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following and see if it helps ([source](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6dca45940d766956)):

```
String description = "Turkish characters here";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description); 
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(description).toString());
```

Comment: it is not recognize the html tag

Comment: @ersyn61 What `html` tag are you referring to?

Comment: I use your code and ımport html but same issue. turkish charackters doesnt seen

Comment: it is not support some porteguse ,spanish ,italian characters too.

Comment: @ersyn61 Hmm then I'm not sure either. I'll look into this and see if I can find a solution that works.

Comment: I write this : TextView.setText("\u015File") and yes it is seen "şile"
but I write "\u015File" this in my .txt and in code I write extView.setText(x) ..: x is reading .txt and getting "u015File" but now it seems "u015File" not "şile" what can ı do?

Comment: I cant ask question anymore, please let me ask again

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020260/display-unicode-characters-in-textview-android

Answer (score 3):

This to me screams: character-encoding issue. A lot of software (eg browsers, database clients) robustly handle unexpected bytes by replacing them with question marks. But Turkish characters are supported by "UTF-8", Android's default charset.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29

You may want to start by checking that your charset is indeed set to UTF-8/16 or ISO-8859-9 (Turkish). If that isn't the problem, it could be the font itself.

If that still doesn't solve the problem, I would post a small example of the code you are using to display the text. From file to database to database connection to web browser, there are many places where conversion can happen.

Comment: I want to my textview support all language characters? what can ı do

Comment: Please post a small example of your code and where you are seeing the issue. UTF8 encoding supports foreign language characters.

Comment: in my manifest : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  but when ı want to use spanish or turkish characters in textview dont seem

Comment: getinput.settex("grávida");
         this is seems like this : gr?vida

Comment: it is not support some porteguse ,spanish ,italian characters too.