# Turkish characters in Android Textview

Tags: android

I made an android app. For different languages. But it does not work for turkish characters.How can I solve this problem?
I am loading strings. But when it comes to turkish characters "çile" lets say it prints something different.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these below links, it has been answered.

[How can I use Turkish characters like 'ş ç ı ö' in an Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069716/how-can-i-use-turkish-characters-like-s-c-i-o-in-an-android-textview)

[Android. WebView and loadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata/9312031#9312031)

[Unicode characters not displayed in TextView.setText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext)